# How to add if into form builder in Symfony

Tags: symfony

I need to add extra input into my contact form for specific localisation and I'm looking for a solution that could do something like this:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
    ->add(input)
    if ($locale == "locale") {
        ->add(extrainput)
    }
;
```

Insted of creating two form builders with if and else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add all of them, then you can do that :

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
    ->add('input')
    ->add('extrainput')
    ->getForm(); 
if($test) {
    $form->remove('extrainput');
}
```

Comment: you can do $form->add('extrainput') too, don't forget ->getForm()

Comment: getForm() has to be used again in if? Or is it enough once in the CreateFormBuilder()?

Comment: only to CreateFormBuilder() :)